# Pandas Difference Between Dates in Months

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

i have a dataframe date column with below values

```
2015-01-01
2015-02-01
2015-03-01
2015-07-01
2015-08-01
2015-10-01
2015-11-01
2016-02-01
```

i want to find the difference of these values in months, as below

```
  date_dt       diff_mnts
2015-01-01        0
2015-02-01        1
2015-03-01        1
2015-07-01        4 
2015-08-01        1
2015-10-01        2
2015-11-01        1
2016-02-01        3
```

i tried to use the `diff()` method to calculate the days and then convert to  `astype('timedelta64(M)')`. but in those cases, when days are less than 30 - its showing month difference values as 0. please let me know, if there is any easy built in function, which i can try in this case.

Comment: get the month value of each date and subtract it?

Comment: @Usernamenotfound - that wont work then there is a change in year value.

Comment: @codeforester - that question was slightly different from my problem. in mine - date values were in a single dataframe/variable. also solutions mentioned for that question would not solve my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Option 1**
Change the period and call `diff`.

```
df    
        Date
0 2015-01-01
1 2015-02-01
2 2015-03-01
3 2015-07-01
4 2015-08-01
5 2015-10-01
6 2015-11-01
7 2016-02-01

df.Date.dtype
dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

```
df.Date.dt.to_period('M').diff().fillna(0)

0    0
1    1
2    1
3    4
4    1
5    2
6    1
7    3
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

---

**Option 2**
Alternatively, call `diff` on `dt.month`, but you'll need to account for gaps over a year (solution improved thanks to @galaxyan!) -

```
i = df.Date.dt.year.diff() * 12 
j = df.Date.dt.month.diff()

(i + j).fillna(0).astype(int)

0    0
1    1
2    1
3    4
4    1
5    2
6    1
7    3
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

Caveat (thanks to  for spotting it) is that this wouldn't work for gaps over a year.

Comment: option 1 is great, but option 2 wouldn't work if there are 2 years gap.

Comment: @galaxyan Cheers, well spotted.... added the caveat (I don't know I workaround for that).

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Mistake in my code was - I tried to find the days different first and then changing the period to M.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ df = df.assign(diff=df.Date.dt.year.diff()*12 + df.Date.dt.month.diff()).fillna(0)

Comment: @galaxyan Taking the `diff` of the year! That did come to my mind but couldn't figure out the code. Genius!

Answer (score -1):

Try the following steps

- Cast the column into datetime format.
- Use the `.month` method to get the month number
- Use the shift() method in pandas to calculate difference

example code will look something like this

```
df['diff_mnts'] = date_dt.month - date_dt.shift().month
```

Comment: This isn't a complete answer, as it doesn't account for negative differences. Also, I didn't downvote.